# Does flex-grow interact with images? How can I find the problem with my code?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

```
<section>
  <div class="section-header">
      <h5>Who we are</h5>
      <h1>Our Professional Team</h1>
       <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt, eaque.</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="images-flex-grid-33">
     <img src="../image_resources/team/person1.jpg">
     <img src="../image_resources/team/person2.jpg">
     <img src="../image_resources/team/person3.jpg">
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.images-flex-grid-33{
  display: flex;
  flex:1;
}

.images-flex-grid-33 img{
  max-width: 30%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

With the above CSS I'm trying to allot the empty spaces of flex so that the images can grow equally, but they are not reacting!

Comment: try min-width:0 to the image

Comment: I believe te issue is that you are setting a max-width, which prevents the img from growing to its required even size. Try removing the max-width and styling from there.

Comment: Yaaahh... i got it as i declared max-width i'm not allowing the element to grow... but also looks like there is a bug with flow-grow's integration on images

Answer (score 0):

```css
.images-flex-grid-33{
  display: flex;
  flex:1;
}

.images-flex-grid-33 img{
  max-width: 30%;
  border-radius: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0 0.3vh;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="section-header">
      <h5>Who we are</h5>
      <h1>Our Professional Team</h1>
       <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt, eaque.</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="images-flex-grid-33">
     <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IR8KR2u.jpg">
     <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IR8KR2u.jpg">
     <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IR8KR2u.jpg">
  </div>
</section>
```

I do not know if this is what you need, if not tell me exactly how and I will try to make it for you! P.s i used a random photo xD